# Rails undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I have a method 'calc_price' that was working previously, and still works in console, but is now giving me the following error in a browser:

```
NoMethodError in Quotes#index

undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

18:             Price: $<%= f.calc_price %><br />

app/models/quote.rb:33:in `block in calc_price'
app/models/quote.rb:13:in `calc_price'
app/views/quotes/index.html.erb:18:in `block in _app_views_quotes_index_html_erb__1788058106025144185_70227449765940'
app/views/quotes/index.html.erb:15:in `each' 
app/views/quotes/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_quotes_index_html_erb__1788058106025144185_70227449765940'
```

The fact that it still works in console is confusing to me, especially since I didn't change the method at all for it to break. The method:

```
def calc_price
    self.items.each do |item|
        pr = if item.amount < 10
            item.product.pricerange0
        elsif item.amount < 25 
            item.product.pricerange1
        elsif item.amount < 50 
            item.product.pricerange2
        elsif item.amount < 100
            item.product.pricerange3
        elsif item.amount < 250
            item.product.pricerange4
        elsif item.amount < 500
            item.product.pricerange5
        end
        screens = 0
        sd = item.shirtdesigns.count
        pd = item.pantdesigns.count
        screens = (sd+pd)
        screenprice = (screens*25)
        inkprice = ((item.inkcolors-1)*0.5)
        newprice = ((pr+inkprice)*item.amount+screenprice)
        item.price = newprice
        item.save
    end
    newprice = self.items.sum('price')
    self.price = newprice
    self.save
    return self.price
end
```

quote controller

```
def index
  @quote = Quote.find(:all)
  @myquotes = Quote.find(:all, :conditions => { :user_email => current_user.email })
end
```

I tried adding screenprice = 0, newprice = 0 and inkprice = 0 to see if that would make a difference but it did not.

If it still works in console does that mean maybe its not the method itself that is broken?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Seems that `pr` is nil.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev pr is defined by the if statement at the top, item.product.pricerange0-5 are decimals.

Comment: That's a broken method if I've ever seen one. You should probably start by reconsidering how you're modeling your pricing, writing tests for your code, refactoring your massive 6-branch conditional statement and the procedure following it into more concise methods, and removing explicit callers where they're not needed (e.g. almost all of your `self.`'s).

Comment: @coreyward could you elaborate on which self.'s arent needed?

Comment: Self is an implicit receiver — you don't need to specify it unless the intent is ambiguous to the interpreter. When you're not doing assignment, `self` is almost never needed. In your code, `self.` can be dropped from `self.items.*`, `self.save`, `self.price` (but not `self.price=`).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me

Answer (score 0):

`pr` is most likely nil.  An item with an amount greater than 500 would result in `pr` being nil in the code above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the >500 amount, I've changed that in my method. In the current case however the amount is 57 and pr = productpricerange2 which == 8.50.